# Can the OpenRasta, ServiceStack and RestCake API's be used on frameworks other than .NET?

Tags: .net, wcf, api, openrasta, servicestack

I know these API's are used for doing something easier than WCF (in terms of config and performance) for .NET, but I wanted to know if these API's can be used on other frameworks too?

Thanks,
Thothathri

Comment: What exactly do you mean "used on other frameworks"? Any client can consume the REST API, since it's all just standard HTTP.  ServiceStack (and perhaps the others) can also expose SOAP endpoints, and you can consume those with any SOAP client (.NET or otherwise).

Comment: @kevin : can the wcf service also be consumed by any client (.NET or otherwise) ?

Comment: the WCF service can be consumed by most SOAP clients.  I'd say all, but there's probably some that won't work... although any that don't likely have other issues.  We have customers that connect with Java, PHP, custom tools, etc. to our WCF service without issue.

Comment: You are asking the wrong question - that is not about API but about protocols / architecture approaches used when exposing the service. Once you understand what SOAP or REST is you will understand how interoperability works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All web service frameworks just serve JSON/XML/SOAP over HTTP - this is the path of greatest interoperability.

As for [all](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/) [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/Backbone.Todos/) [demos](http://www.servicestack.net/RedisStackOverflow/), [they're](http://www.servicestack.net/RestFiles/) [all](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.MovieRest/) consumed live with HTML/JavaScript, so no .NET on the client to speak of. Of course if you use ServiceStack's C# clients you get the benefit of a strong-typed [sync](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RestFiles/RestFiles.Tests/SyncRestClientTests.cs) and [async](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/blob/master/src/RestFiles/RestFiles.Tests/AsyncRestClientTests.cs) clients.